# Calling oracle stored procedure from java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I am calling a stored procedure in oracle from Java client.

There is a problem when passing string of length about 80 characters from Java into procedure parameter.

Although it works fine for smaller string.

The error thrown was "

> numeric or value error: character string buffer too small"

What could be the reason?

Comment: What's the type of the input parameter?

Comment: Varun what is the data type of your input parameter and how much is the length of the parameter field?

Comment: Its a VARCHAR2 type. I guess there should not be a problem with that,

Comment: I am using String on the Java side.

Comment: Maybe something's using an intermediate variable that is too short in your procedure (or a column's type is too narrow). Would need to see the procedure and involved types to debug this further.

Comment: check this too:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509643/ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-buffer-too-small-err

Answer (score 0):

Check the IN parameter in the procedure to which you are passing this 80 char string. Looks like you are trying to assign it to a param which can only hold a smaller string.

Comment: You can't specify/restrict the length on a parameter; you can only declare the type as `VARCHAR2`, trying to set the length like `VARCHAR2(80)` won't compile. (Actually you can use a `%TYPE` reference too, but that also ignores the length and only uses the data type).

Comment: since i am using the parameter in search criteria I can not use %TYPE,this parameter contains list of csv in use in search query.